# Transform paypal curl get access token request into guzzle

Tags: curl, paypal, internal, guzzle

i'm needing some help with paypal rest api.

I'm using guzzle as http client to consume paypal api

When i try paypal example in command line with curl, it does works

but when i want reproduce it with guzzle i always get Internal 500 ERROR from paypal..

Here's paypal curl example from official docs ( check here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/ ) :

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "clientId:clientSecret" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Here's my guzzle code :

```
/**
 * Etape 1 récuperer un access token
 */
$authResponse = $client->get("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", [
    'auth' =>  [$apiClientId, $apiClientSecret, 'basic'],
    'body' => ['grant_type' => 'client_credentials'],
    'headers' => [
    'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
    'Accept'     => 'application/json' 
    ]
]);

echo $authResponse->getBody();
```

I've tried with auth basic, digest but none worked so far.

Thanks for any help on this !

Comment: One thing to note, I think your `'body'` should be `'query'`, but for me, it didn't make a different.

Comment: I finally used a custom curl code. But i guess the problem is that we should use guzzle extension for handling oauth authentication trough a bearer header.

Checkout out this link http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/plugins/oauth-plugin.html

Answer (score 9):

This is using **guzzlehttp**

```
$uri = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';
$clientId = \\Your client_id which you got on sign up;
$secret = \\Your secret which you got on sign up;

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
        'headers' =>
            [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
               'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ],
        'body' => 'grant_type=client_credentials',

        'auth' => [$clientId, $secret, 'basic']
    ]
);

$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

$access_token = $data['access_token'];
```

Comment: good parsing the answer

Comment: help here Mr Pranay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363765/paypal-integration-with-laravel-using-v2-php-sdk

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is on the first line.

```
    $authResponse = $client->get
```

It should be a post.

```
     $authResponse = $client->post
```

I had a similar issue for a little bit.

EDIT: I also fond that if you want to use JSON for the body of a request either use json_encode or replace body with json, guzzle will handle the rest. In your previous code...

```
$authResponse = $client->post("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", [
    'auth' =>  [$apiClientId, $apiClientSecret, 'basic'],
    'json' => ['grant_type' => 'client_credentials'],
    'headers' => [
        'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
        'Accept' => 'application/json' 
    ]
```

]);

Comment: please Andrew see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363765/paypal-integration-with-laravel-using-v2-php-sdk

Answer (score 2):

I get help from 'Filippo De Santis' code. He already have implemented a very nice PayPal REST API Client with guzzle 3.9.1 which you can find it on https://github.com/p16/paypal-rest-api-client and you can just use his code.

But if you want to still use Guzzle. So I get help from his code and use the following code and it works perfectly for me

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();

$clientId = "xxxxxxxxx";
$secret = "yyyyyyyyyy";

$request = $client->createRequest(
    'POST',
    'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
    array(
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ),
    'grant_type=client_credentials',
    array(
        'auth' => array($clientId, $secret),
    )
);

$response = $client->send($request);
$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);        

var_dump($data);
```

Just notice that I use guzzle 3.9.1

Comment: The part with 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is actually essential for live server

Comment: help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363765/paypal-integration-with-laravel-using-v2-php-sdk

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the below code to get your token. for Newer Guzzle version

```
$response = $client->post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', [
            'auth' =>  [config('your.client_id'), config('your.secret'), 'basic'],
            'form_params' => ['grant_type' => 'client_credentials'],
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Accept-Language' => 'en_US'
            ],
        ]);

        return $response->getBody();
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363765/paypal-integration-with-laravel-using-v2-php-sdk