# PayPal integration failure with Laravel using v2 PHP SDK

Tags: laravel, paypal

I'm tryng to integrate simple payments through PayPal with a sandbox Business account.  I found the PayPal-PHP-SDK for v1/payments is deprecated so I just wanted to test the newer  v2 SDK with Laravel.

While trying to test the demo PayPal, I got more than one error like
First one is net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT that's happen without any event on the paypal button
When i click on paypal button i found this error
Create_order_error {err: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response':
Also this error
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
Js?client-id=test&currency=USD:2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream Already read
click_initiate_payment_reject {err: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response':…al.com/

So I installed this

```
 composer require paypal/paypal-payouts-sdk ~1.0.0
```

dependent on this repository :

```
 https://github.com/paypal/Payouts-PHP-SDK
```

But I don't know if I'm using the right package... this is the code from GitHub:

```
   $request = new PayoutsPostRequest();
      $body= json_decode(
                '{
                    "sender_batch_header":
                    {
                      "email_subject": "SDK payouts test txn"
                    },
                    "items": [
                    {
                      "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
                      "receiver": "smyddddddddddddt@business.example.com",
                      "note": "Your 160 payout",
                      "sender_item_id": "Test_txn_12",
                      "amount":
                      {
                        "currency": "EUR",
                        "value": "160.00"
                      }
                    }]
                  }',             
                true);
      $request->body = $body;
      $en = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
      $client = new PayPalHttpClient($en);
      $response = $client->execute($request);
```

i don't don't know if i'm using the right paypal button like this

```
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
     <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Call your server to set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('{{route("create-demo")}}', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    console.log(res.json());
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    return orderData.orderID;
                });
            },

            // Call your server to finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
```

So if someone can help with details I would love if you can share a good resource

-----Edited-----

To send request using guzzle but i got this error
`400 Bad Request`
response: {"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed,

this is the code :

```
 try {
        
        $client = new Client();
        $req = $client->request('POST', $uri, [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
                //'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization' => 'Basic <'.$clientId.':'.$clientSecret.'>',
                'PayPal-Request-Id' => '7b92603e-77ed-4896-8e78-5dea2050476a'
            ],
            'auth' => [$clientId, $clientSecret, 'basic'],
            'json' => ['grant_type' => 'client_credentials'],
            'form_params' => [
                'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
                'purchase_units' => [               
                    [
                        "reference_id" => "d9f80740-38f0-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f718b",
                        'amount' => [
                            'currency_code' => 'USD',
                            'value' => '100.00'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "payment_source" => [
                    "paypal" => [
                        "experience_context" => [
                            "payment_method_preference" => "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED",
                            "payment_method_selected" => "PAYPAL",
                            "brand_name" => "EXAMPLE INC",
                            "locale" => "en-US",
                            "landing_page" => "LOGIN",
                            "shipping_preference" => "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
                            "user_action" => "PAY_NOW",
                            "return_url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/paypal/success",
                            "cancel_url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/paypal/cancelled",
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]

        ]);
        $response = $client->send($req);
        return $response;
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return $e;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Payouts-PHP-SDK is for sending money, not a PayPal Checkout integration.

You can use the Checkout-PHP-SDK to abstract Orders v2 calls, although it was also deprecated recently and won't be maintained. The officially supported alternative is to do your own HTTPS calls (using curl or similar) to first obtain an access_token and then do each call.

The frontend approval JS in your question seems cut off/incomplete, but looks correct as far as it goes; [this is the demo site to reference](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast answer yes i don't write in my question the full frontend but i don't know how to use using curl or similar can you share some toturial for curl with laravel

Comment: curl is the general PHP solution, laravel may have its own functions/client for abstracting such calls -- yeah, looks like it uses guzzle: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client

Comment: The PayPal Orders API is documented at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create  see the upper left Authentication tab for getting an access_token using a client-id and secret

Comment: That's...an interesting mess. Do not use the Authorization header in conjunction with auth. Do not use form_params in conjunction with json.  The call with grant_type=client_credentials happens first, to obtain an access token. Any call with a json body is a separate step

Comment: Mr Preston i got this error "status":""PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED","payment_source" that when i tried to set the return_url and cancel_url through payment_source with redirecting approve status without js button but i got this PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED because using payment_source  instead application_context

Comment: Mr preston when i use payment_source the error occur but when i don't use payment_source it's okay and redirect me ro the paypal to complete the purchase so how to handle that i know you answer someone in another post but please give me more info specially with api v2

Comment: No reason to use a return and cancel URL nor redirect. Use the JS SDK server pattern for approval: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: i used the cURL to return the url in links to let buyer to buy so to use your way what i will return through the JS SDk button to redirect and how to set my custom return_url and cancel_url

Comment: Don't set any URLs in the API. You don't need them. When the JS SDK createOrder function uses fetch to call the create order path on your server have it do the API call to PayPal and return the resulting (response) JSON string of a newly created order.

Comment: The js SDK button don't redirect me but when i redirect manual it worked the point here how to set url after suecss or fail or cancel with my custom route that what i want to do

Comment: Correct, it doesn't redirect. It opens a popup for the approval flow, this is what you should use.  Redirecting after success is something you would do in the onApprove function, using javascript

Comment: thanks mr preston it's worked with cURL extension i marked as solution